# How to extract data from a get request with Ruby Grape

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-grape, grape-api, yo

I'm experimenting with grape and Ruby by trying to make a Yo API callback function.

I can get simple examples up and running like this . . .

```
resource :loc do
    get ':loc' do        
        params.to_yaml
    end
end
```

How would I go about extracting `username` and `x` and `y` coordinates into separate ruby variable given a callback with the following format?

```
http://yourcallbackurl.com/yourendpoint?username=THEYOER&location=42.360091;-71.094159
```

When the location data is screwed up . . .

```
--- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
username: sfsdfsdf
location: '42.360091'
"-71.094159": 
route_info: !ruby/object:Grape::Route
  options:
    :prefix: 
    :version: v1
    :namespace: "/loc"
    :method: GET
    :path: "/:version/loc/:loc(.:format)"
    :params:
      loc: ''
    :compiled: !ruby/regexp /\A\/(?<version>v1)\/loc\/(?<loc>[^\/.?]+)(?:\.(?<format>[^\/.?]+))?\Z/
version: v1
loc: toto
format: txt
```

Comment: The problems come from the pesky semicolon in the location data. If it was just a comma, then the location contains both numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [how Rack::Utils works](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L104-L116). Default params separators are "&" and ";" (its totally legal according to HTTP standard). So you have to parse query string by yourself here.

```
location = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env['QUERY_STRING'], '&')['location']
coordinates = location.split(';')
```

UPD: typo with hash key fixed.

Comment: if I replace `params.to_yaml` with your suggestion, the location variable is empty

Comment: @learnvst typo fixed, please try once again. The idea here is that `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env['QUERY_STRING'], '&')` returns you a hash of params separated ONLY by "&". Everything else is trivial.